# Published Map Services in SRID 4326

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-server, wgs84, arcgis-portal

I've been tasked with creating webservices of individual layers in Portal for ArcGIS.  The data itself is stored in SQL Server in SRID 4326 (WGS84 unprojected). I'm wondering if it's a better idea to decide on a projection and project the data before I publish the services? The services will be used in an application (not an ESRI app) and they are pretty much for display purposes.

Comment: My concern is that it delivers distances in decimal degrees. I was under the impression that meant it was not suitable for 2D representations. Am I wrong in that thinking?

Comment: EPSG:4326 is a 2D coordinate reference using lat/long decimal degrees. If you want m as the coordinates, then you'll need a different CRS.  Whether or not one is better than the other will depend on the application.

Comment: Web services can do reprojection on the fly,  so you don't have to choose one over the other, but it might be worth considering which CRS, will be used most and have that as the native CRS

Comment: You'll need to add details of what you want to do, for someone to give you the likely better strategy

Comment: Apologies thought you meant not a CRS, but you do mean projected CRS, vs geographic CRS

Comment: Yes a projected one. Since the application might not project on the fly might measurements in 4326 not be as accurate as a projected CRS?

Comment: How accurate do you need for a map, shown on the Web, mainly for display?

Comment: How accurate is your input data?

Comment: What is the spatial extent?